# How to transform three column layout into two column layout and two into one using css

Tags: html, css

[image]

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1694Z1xMTKAkHwKheGzrViSRnr_EXno7XBl_Cf38Xrc0/pub

I am using media rule for specific devices.Can someone explain me the logic to the above problem.I have created three tables with a single column each and filled the cell with image and title.how can i convert these three column into two columnn for screen size of 1024x720.

Comment: This is very simple to do... though Im not really sure how I am suppose to help you with YOUR code, if you do not provide any???  If you want a general answer, then google 'responsive grid'.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1694Z1xMTKAkHwKheGzrViSRnr_EXno7XBl_Cf38Xrc0/pub

Comment: here please take a look at the code its slightly difficult cause i am creating cells dynamically using jquery

Comment: Oh wow... Why are you using a table for this??

Comment: i am not much aware of grid layout so i used table

Comment: cause i am not much aware of grid layout so i used table,please i really need a help with this any specific tutorial that can help me?

Comment: Ya you shouldn't be doing this with a table. If you don't understand responsive grids, I'd suggest using a framework like bootstrap or foundation.

Comment: use twitter bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

3x2 boxes with 1024 width, 2x3 boxes , 1x6 boxes for small screens

http://output.jsbin.com/jecinulepu/14

> HTML

```
<div id ="container">
<div class="box">
<span>title</span>
</div><div class="box">
<span>title</span>
</div><div class="box">
<span>title</span>
</div><div class="box">
<span>title</span>
</div><div class="box">
<span>title</span>
</div><div class="box">
<span>title</span>
</div>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
#container {
  max-width:1024px;
  height:100%;
}

.box{
  width:300px;
  height:250px;
  background:grey;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #999;
}

.box span {
  width:300px;
  height:50px;
  background:white;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:40px;
  margin-top:200px
}

/* Portrait */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 800px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

  #container {
  max-width:800px;
  }
  }



/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {

  #container {
  max-width:480px;
  }

}
```

Comment: Your code is pretty rough. You have rules overriding rules inside the same selector. 'float: left; display: block;'?  Also, no need to be targeting device only... Or portrait only for that matter.  I would strongly advice not using this example.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method,

## container {

max-width:1024px;
  height:100%;
}

.box{
  width:300px;
  height:250px;
  background:grey;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #999;
}

.box span {
  width:300px;
  height:50px;
  background:white;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:40px;
  margin-top:200px
}

/* Portrait */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 800px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

  #container {
  max-width:800px;
  }

.box{
  width:100%!important;
}

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {

  #container {
  max-width:480px;
  }

.box{
  width:100%!important;
}
}